# Is there a way to destroy a Tkinter object that is stored in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, destroy

I'm trying to display a lot of appearing and disappearing object in Tkinter. I store those in a normal list for easy access and to be easily able to loop through them. I also want some of the objects to disappear and not come back (and thus be entirely deleted).

I've tried to use `.destroy()` because that should work to destroy an object in Tkinter:

```
loc = 0
list_with_objects.append(create_oval(1, 2, 3, 4)
list_with_objects[loc].destroy()
```

However, this doesn't work and only gives me the following error message: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'destroy'`
Any thoughts on how I could do this would be really much appreciated.
Here is my full code:

```
from random import choices, randint
import tkinter


class World(tkinter.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, size):

        self.xLim = size[0]
        self.yLim = size[1]

        super().__init__(master, width=self.xLim, height=self.yLim, bg='#27c945')
        self.pack()

        self.organisms = []
        self.organTags = []

        self.run()


    def run(self):

        for organism, organTag in zip(self.organisms, self.organTags):
            organism.movement()
            self.move(organTag, organism.xDis, organism.yDis)
            
            if organism.x >= self.xLim - 10 or organism.x <= 10:
                organism.xDis *= -1
            if organism.y >= self.yLim - 10 or organism.y <= 10:
                organism.yDis *= -1
                
        toKill = []
        for loc in range(len(self.organisms)):
            if choices([0, 1], [90, 10])[0] == 1:
                toKill.append(loc)

        self.killOrganism(*toKill)
        self.newOrganism()

        self.after(25, self.run)


    def newOrganism(self):
        new = organism(self.xLim, self.yLim)
        self.organisms.append(new)
        self.organTags.append(self.create_oval(new.x - 10, new.y - 10, new.x + 10, new.y + 10, fill='black'))


    def killOrganism(self, *args):
        for loc in sorted(args, reverse=True):
            self.organTags[loc].destroy()
            self.organTags.pop(loc)
            self.organisms.pop(loc)
            

class organism():
    def __init__(self, xLim, yLim):
        self.x = randint(10, xLim - 10)
        self.y = randint(10, yLim - 10)

        self.xLim = xLim - 10
        self.yLim = yLim - 10

        self.xDis = randint(-1, 1)
        self.yDis = randint(-1, 1)


    def movement(self):
        if choices((0, 1), [99, 1]) == [1]:
            self.xDis = randint(-3, 3)
            self.yDis = randint(-2, 2)

        self.x += self.xDis
        self.y += self.yDis


worldWidth = 1280
worldLenght = 960
Map = tkinter.Tk()
Map.geometry(str(worldWidth) + 'x' + str(worldLenght))
field = World(Map, (worldWidth, worldLenght))
field.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like your list contains integers, rather than Tkinter objects that have a `destroy` method on them. The code can't be run, though, as `create_oval` doesn't exist - you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you mean create_oval doesn't exist? I also have earlier version where newOrganism and killOrganism aren't in there yet and that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_oval` returns an `int` which doesn't have a `destroy` method. Luckily, this int is the reference of the shape in your canvas. You can delete it with `your_canvas.delete(ref)`. So in your code:

```
def killOrganism(self, *args):
    for loc in sorted(args, reverse=True):
        self.delete(self.organTags[loc])
        self.organTags.pop(loc)
        self.organisms.pop(loc)
```